# Verificando se o CPF é único com JQuery validate remote

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery.validate

Estou fazendo um formulário que verifica se o CPF já existe em uma base de dados.
No meu JS eu uso a biblioteca JQuery Validate

```
$('#form').validate({
        rules:{          
            cpf: {
                required: true,
                cpfBR: true,
                remote: "cpfunico.php"
            },
       },
        messages: { 
            cpf: { 
                remote: "CPF já cadastrado." 
           }
       },     
});
```

No arquivo ServerSide eu tenho a seguinte requisição:

```
 if(procuraCpf($_GET['cpf'])){
       echo true;
       // ja tentei também com echo (json_encode(true));
   } else {
        echo false;
    }
```

A função procuraCpf() retorna se encontrou o cpf na base de dados e retorna ao JQuery atraves de uma mensagem true ou false.

O problema está quando o servidor retorna um cpf já cadastrado, e dá a mensagem via Validate. Depois disso todos os cpf´s vão dar a mensagem "CPF já cadastrado". Inspecionei o código e identifiquei que o JQuery Validate emite a mensagem antes mesmo de fazer a requisição no banco para ver se o cpf existe. Não entendo por que isso acontece.

Comment: Já tentaste [**desta forma**](https://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/#example:-makes-the-email-field-required-an-email-and-does-a-remote-request-to-check-if-the-given-address-is-already-taken-in-addition-the-http-method-is-set-to-%22post%22-and-the-username-is-sent-alongside-the-email-address)?

Comment: Já sim, porém o problema continua.

Comment: Substitua `echo true;` por `echo "true";`. O mesmo com `false`

Comment: Conseguiu resolver teu problema? estou enfrentando esse mesmo problema

Comment: Não consegui amigo. Estou fazendo a validação do cpf quando o usuário salva o formulário. Quando conseguir fazer isso, vou aplicar na próxima versão do sistema.